# Finding 2 largest eigenvalues of large-sparse matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I want to find the 1st and 2nd largest eigenvalues of a big, sparse and symmetric matrix (in python). scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh with k=2 gives the second largest eigenvalue with respect to the absolute value - so it's not a good solution. In addition, I can't use numpy methods because my matrix is too big and numpy is too slow... 
I am not sure what is the best solution to this problem - any help is welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr: You can use the `which='LA'` flag as described in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html).**

I quote:

> scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(A, k=6, M=None, sigma=None, **which='LM'**,
>   v0=None, ncv=None, maxiter=None, tol=0, return_eigenvectors=True,
>   Minv=None, OPinv=None, mode='normal')

Emphasis mine.

```
which : str [‘LM’ | ‘SM’ | ‘LA’ | ‘SA’ | ‘BE’]
If A is a complex hermitian matrix, ‘BE’ is invalid. Which k eigenvectors and eigenvalues to find:
‘LM’ : Largest (in magnitude) eigenvalues
‘SM’ : Smallest (in magnitude) eigenvalues
‘LA’ : Largest (algebraic) eigenvalues
‘SA’ : Smallest (algebraic) eigenvalues
‘BE’ : Half (k/2) from each end of the spectrum
```

So, you can specify `which='LA'` instead of the default `LM`.

---

Example:

```
In [19]: A = numpy.random.randn(5,5)

In [20]: numpy.linalg.eig(A+A.T)[0] #Actual Eigenvalues
Out[20]: array([ 3.32906012,  0.88700157, -1.16620472, -3.54512752, -2.43562899])

In [21]: sp.eigsh(A+A.T,3)[0] #Three Largest (in Magnitude). What you don't want
Out[21]: array([-3.54512752, -2.43562899,  3.32906012])

In [22]: sp.eigsh(A+A.T,3,which='LA')[0] #Three Largest. What you do want

Out[22]: array([-1.16620472,  0.88700157,  3.32906012])
```